# Following Ubuntu OS update and reboot serial ports not recognized inside Arduino IDE

Tags: usb, serial-port

Serial ports ttyACM0 and ttyUSB* have disappeared after update to 20.04 LTS and reboot.
Tried going from Grub kernel 5.15.0-52-generic to 5.15.0-48-generic.
These particular ports are referenced inside the Arduino IDE 1.8.19 software platform. Is this somehow an issue with module uhci_hcd?

This output is currently what listing usb indicates:

```
ed@ed-G41MT-S2PT:~$ lsusb
```

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

This output is what listing usb indicated prior to the problem:

```
ed@ed-G41MT-S2PT:~$ lsusb
```

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c315 Logitech, Inc. Classic Keyboard 200

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 007: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge                        <  for ESP32

Bus 004 Device 013: ID 03eb:2145 Atmel Corp. ATMEGA328P-XMINI (CDC ACM)   < for UNO Wifi

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

ed@ed-G41MT-S2PT:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0

crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Oct 23 21:31 /dev/ttyACM0           < for UNO Wifi Rev2

ed@ed-G41MT-S2PT:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Oct 23 20:47 /dev/ttyUSB0

dmsg output:

```
300.577326] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
```

[  316.019449] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[  331.643546] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[  331.883253] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd

[  347.261737] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[  362.886433] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[  362.994477] usb usb4-port2: attempt power cycle

[  362.994488] usb usb4-port2: failed to disable port power

[  363.122494] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd

[  373.718020] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 4, error -110

[  373.845009] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd

[  384.471051] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 5, error -110

[  384.471080] usb usb4-port2: unable to enumerate USB device

[  435.568453] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd

[  450.965130] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[  466.573514] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[  466.809513] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using uhci_hcd

[  482.189669] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[  497.809646] usb 4-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110

[  497.917671] usb usb4-port2: attempt power cycle

[  497.917685] usb usb4-port2: failed to disable port power

[  498.045657] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using uhci_hcd

[  508.637553] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 8, error -110

[  508.765551] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using uhci_hcd

[  519.389402] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 9, error -110

[  519.389433] usb usb4-port2: unable to enumerate USB device

[  526.945401] perf: interrupt took too long (2502 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750

[  891.311959] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure
on pipe A (start=56121 end=56122) time 1312 us, min 894, max 899,
scanline start 869, end 9

[ 2109.011458] perf: interrupt took too long (3130 > 3127), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63750

[ 3073.720481] usb 1-7.3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci

[ 3078.952378] usb 1-7.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32

[ 3079.160367] usb 1-7.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32

[ 3079.348364] usb 1-7.3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci

[ 3079.456365] usb 1-7.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32

[ 3079.664360] usb 1-7.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32

[ 3079.772426] usb 1-7-port3: attempt power cycle

[ 3080.376346] usb 1-7.3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci

[ 3080.792339] usb 1-7.3: device not accepting address 8, error -32

[ 3080.872337] usb 1-7.3: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci

[ 3081.288331] usb 1-7.3: device not accepting address 9, error -32

[ 3081.288428] usb 1-7-port3: unable to enumerate USB device